# Overriding kafka key and value deserializers in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I was reading the spark Kafka integration doc and saw that I cannot override key.deserializer ,value.deserializer and schema.registry.url.  I just wanted to know why is this restriction imposed. I was trying to decode Avro messages from spark and I had to write custom logic, whereas this is provided by other Kafka clients libraries.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably get a more direct answer from the Spark dev mailing lists, but my thought is that the Kafka serializer interfaces and subclasses are not serializable objects themselves, so cannot be instantiated at the driver level, and would need to be reconfigured per batch